# Getting notified when alert manager can not notify

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-sns, prometheus-alertmanager

So I have a Prometheus installation on EKS, with AlertManager sending notification to an AWS SNS topic.
All is working, but I wish to get notified if the alertmanager is acting badly, mainly if there is a problem with sending the notification.
I have the default alarms AlertmanagerClusterFailedToSendAlerts, which work but, since it triggers when it can't send notification, I won't be notified.

How do you get notified for this specific problem?

Comment: Depending on what is the reason of alertmanager's inability to send notification. If it's channel problem - add secondary, more reliable channel and send those alerts there. If it's more general problem with networking or something - nothing short of new prometheus/alertmanger stack for monitoring current one wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need a way to monitor the AlertManager right?

You can use lambda to probe AlertManager(pod or anything is convenient for you, which depend on the CNI you used, or whether you want to expose the svc of AlertManager), send SNS if Failed